# How can I get Javascript to run from inside html when opened from html file

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to create a challenge page written in HTML and javascript but when i open the first page in chrome the HTML loads, but not the javascript, note I am running from a file as mentioned in the question.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Best bank ever!
        </title>
        <h1>
            John's Secure Online Bank
        </h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Trust us with your dosh!</p>
        <p>Visit us in store or ring 555-1666 to open an account</p>
    </body>
    <script>
        var correct_sur = "Haxor";
        var correct_first = "Leet";


        var surname = prompt('Greetings friend, may I enquire as to your surname? This is so we can log you in to your account.');
        var firstname = prompt('Now please may I enquire as to your first name?');


        if (correct_sur = surname) {
            alert("Surname found in database");
            if (correct_first = firstname) {
            alert("First name found in database! Loading Account Password Panel now};
            window.open ('password.html','_self',false);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: There is an error in your javascript code.

`alert("First name found in database! Loading Account Password Panel now};`
should be

`alert("First name found in database! Loading Account Password Panel now")};`

Comment: … you’re also assigning instead of comparing multiple times, like: `if (correct_sur = surname)` should be `if (correct_sur === surname)`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `"` and a `)` on the end of `alert("First name found in database! Loading Account Password Panel now};` It should be `alert("First name found in database! Loading Account Password Panel now")};`

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <title>
       Best bank ever!
      </title>
      <h1>
       John's Secure Online Bank
      </h1>
     </head>
     <body>
      <p>Trust us with your dosh!</p>
      <p>Visit us in store or ring 555-1666 to open an account</p>
     </body>
     <script>
      var correct_sur = "Haxor";
      var correct_first = "Leet";
      
      
      var surname = prompt('Greetings friend, may I enquire as to your surname? This is so we can log you in to your account.');
      var firstname = prompt('Now please may I enquire as to your first name?');
      
      
      if (correct_sur = surname) {
       alert("Surname found in database");
       if (correct_first = firstname) {
       alert("First name found in database! Loading Account Password Panel now")};
       window.open ('password.html','_self',false);
      }
     </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the comments. Please don't add fixing typos as answers as it adds no value to future readers. If typo is the issue, it should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: How should I then explain the problem to him? @adiga

Comment: You can add a comment and if the OP says it's caused by typo, you should flag is as off-topic. This will get deleted by [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) as it adds no value to this site.

Comment: I understand thanks for telling next time i will comment :) @adiga